Rician Frequency Selective Channel Model
I have a question about Rician channel with $L$ taps.
The frequency selective Rician fading channels with delay spread of $L = 6$ taps are considered for both direct link and reflecting link, where the first tap is set as the deterministic line-of-sight (LoS) component and the remaining taps are non-LoS components following the Rayleigh fading distribution, with $\eta$ being the ratio of the total power of non-LoS components to that of LoS component.
Is this a correct MATLAB code for the above definition?
h = zeros(L, 1); 
h(1) = sqrt(eta/(1 + eta)); % LoS component 
h(2:end) = sqrt(1/(2*(1 + eta))) * (randn(L-1, 1) + 1i * randn(L-1, 1)); % Non-LoS components

